Go http request, "read: connection reset by peer"
I read the answer in Go http.Get, concurrency, and "Connection reset by peer". I set the MaxConnsPerHost to equal the number of concurrent requests. But the same request comes again, read tcp 127.0.0.1:52517->127.0.0.1:8080: read: connection reset by peer.
Here is my client code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 400; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int) {
            defer wg.Done()

            url := "http://127.0.0.1:8080/sleep"
            rt := http.Transport{
                MaxIdleConns:        400,
                MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 400,
                MaxConnsPerHost:     400,
                IdleConnTimeout:     20 * time.Second,
                DisableKeepAlives:   false,
            }
            client := http.Client{
                Transport: &rt,
            }
            resp, err := client.Get(url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%d Request to [%s] failed, error: %v\n", i, url, err)
                return
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%d Failed to read response from [%s], error: %v\n", i, url, err)
                return
            }

            fmt.Printf("%d Response from [%s] result: %s\n", i, url, string(body))
        }(i)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

And Here is my server code:
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/sleep", func(c *gin.Context) {
        time.Sleep(10)
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "Slept for 10 seconds",
        })
    })

    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}

Can you tell me how to fix it?

"Can you tell me how to fix it?" There is nothing to "fix". That's how computers work.

Your example is using a separate transport for every client, so the limits aren’t correct and none of the connections can be reused

It's generally worth reading the documentation of every type. Despite how it might be good practice in other languages, in Go a net/http.Client should be reused.

In macOS, set the parameters.
sudo ulimit -n 6049
sudo sysctl -w kern.ipc.somaxconn=1024

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20960#issuecomment-465998114
In Linux, set:
sudo ulimit -n 6049
sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=1024


What is the significance of the magic number 6049 and what are you trading off when you make this change?
